# Can not open a file from .bashrc with the terminal

Tags: terminal, bashrc

I saved a file.txt in my home directory and add that in .bashrc :
`alias tiling='clear; cat tiling-gelp.txt'` 
And I thought if I typed `tiling` in my terminal, the .txt would open, but not?

idea?

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: nothing happens, btw, I use openSUSE

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

just run `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).